# Failed to build gem native extension (Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, mysql2

I have tried to install mysql2 on windows, but it output an error:

> Failed to build gem native extension.

I have installed Devkit, and have tested

```
gem install json --platform=ruby

ruby -rubygems -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.load('[42]').inspect"
```

both of them work fine, but I cannot install any other gems beside json.

Answer (score 0):

To build mysql2 gem on Windows you should use the MySQL C Connector that can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/). You should unzip the folder and do this in cmd/powershell:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir={DIRECTORY OF THE CONNECTOR}
```

[Read this for a full guide.](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2013/10/25/how-to-install-rails-4-on-windows-including-windows-8-and-8-1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried those methods, but they are not work for me. I have moved to Ubuntu and everything works fine now.